# Proving GWT Code Splitting

Tags: gwt, speed-test

i think u all know about GWT Code Splitting because I have been programming on GWT about a month and I've recently know it, lol

I want to prove that a seperate file is going to be downloaded when there is a need for the code inside the runasynccallback in onsuccess. I am trying to invoke this code and use speed tracer to find the new downloaded file but i'm not perceiving it.

Has anyone try this or is there another method to prove this, because i need to show during my project presentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try out the compile report tool mentioned in http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html#splitting

Comment: +1 to this, you should also use Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to verify which code chunks are downloaded, and when.

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the files being downloaded with [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).